# Azure SQL Server firewall configuration using PowerShell not working

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-sql-server

When executing `New-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $SqlServerName -AllowAllAzureIPs`

I get this error: New-AzSqlServerFirewallRule : Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.CertificateCloudCredentials' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Common, Version=2.0.0.0 ...

The user I'm using has Owner rights on the Subscription. I can successfully execute e.g. New-AzSqlServer. However, Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule is also not working. Installed the latest Az.Sql 2.12.0.

When configuring via the Portal I get below error, but the configuration is accepted never the less:
Failed to overwrite firewall rules for server: weu-te-sdb-patrntest-01 and refresh the blade.
ErrorCode: undefined
ErrorMessage: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Comment: Can you try: `ew-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -ServerName "Server01" -FirewallRuleName "Rule01" -StartIpAddress "0.0.0.0" -EndIpAddress "255.255.255.255"`?

Comment: I tried that too, resulting in same error.

Comment: Could you please tell me the version of Azure PowerShell module you installed? You can use  the command `Get-InstalledModule -Name Az` to get it. And could you please tell me the version of  PowerShell you use?

Comment: It's 4.7.0, Az.Sql is 2.12.0. Tried with an earlier Az.Sql version as well and had the same issue. Using PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: I suggest you upgrade Az module to 5.1.0. According to my test, after doing that, it is ok for me.

Comment: Afraid I can't confirm that:
`Get-InstalledModule -Name Az, Az.Accounts, Az.Sql
2.2.1 Az.Accounts
2.12.0 Az.Sql
5.1.0 Az`

Comment: @FelixBodmer Are you able to run `Import-Module Az` without any errors? This could be happening due to module incompatibilities, or when you have multiple versions of modules installed side-by-side. You could always run these cmdlets from [Cloud Shell](https://shell.azure.com/powershell) until you resolve this issue on your machine. Also try [uninstalling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/uninstall-az-ps?view=azps-5.1.0) the Az module and reinstalling it again.

Comment: I de-installed all Az modules and re-installed them. There are no side-by-side installations, no errors.  I do get errors when configuring the SQL Server Firewall using the Azure Portal. I also can't configure using TSQL.

Comment: No sure why, but it's all working now. Also, no longer get error when using Azure Portal.

Comment: @FelixBodmer Glad to know you have it working now. Please post what worked for you as an answer below so it helps others in the community as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the following PowerShell modules did the trick:
Az 5.1.0
Az.Accounts 2.2.2
Az.Sql 2.12.0

Couldn't determine why I had that error in the Portal. However the deployment of a new Azure SQL instance and using above module versions worked.